# Multiply Range, Answer Product of Offset Numbers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

Given an array of `n` real numbers `a[]` and `q` queries. Each query is either an update: multiply range `a[l...r]` by `x`, or a question: tell the product of `1 - a[i]` over range `[l, r]`. All numbers `a[i]` and update `x` are numbers in range `[0, 1)`.

How to solve it faster than brute force, since `n, q` can be as large as `10^5`?

I tried to work out a segment tree but couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree

Comment: As I said in the post, I tried using that but failed. :(